# Blazor how to order or asc a data in table

Tags: blazor, server-side

> Hi i want to display simple table in my blazor and order the data according to date,

```
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var received in Rec)
             {
                                                 
               <tr>
                 <td>@received.DocumentType</td>
                 <td>@received.SenderName</td>
                 <td>@received.Subject</td>
                 <td>@received.Date</td>
                 <td>@received.Forwarded</td>
                 <td>@received.Remarks</td>
               </tr>
                }

            


       </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linq...

```
@using System.Linq

@foreach (var received in Rec.OrderBy(a => a.Date))
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: You are amazing helping newbie like me thaaaaaaankssssssss